# Hierarchical data copy

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I have a master table like below in parent child relation having more than 2000 record

Table Name : MasterTable

```
Id     ReqId       Title                  ParentId
---------------------------------------------------
1      AC1.        Account Control.       null
2      Ac1-1.      account c.             1
3      Ac1-1-1.    account c.             2
```

Another table is Child table where I need to copy data in same hierarchy as below

TableName: ChildTable (sample data after copy)

```
Id     ReqId             Title                  ParentId    MasterTableId
--------------------------------------------------------------------
101    AC1.              Account Control.       null           1
102    Ac1-1.            account c.             101            2
103    Ac1-1-1.          account c.             102            3
```

what I have tried is first inserted the data using insert into... select statement then update the parent id using join with master table and self join but this query takes 2 -5 sec to update.

I have used following query to update the parent Id

```
insert into ChildTable(ReqId,Title,ParentId,MasterTableId) 
select ReqId,Title,null,Id from MasterTable
```

After insertion I am updating the parent id of Child table

```
UPDATE TSR1
set ParentId = TSR2.Id
from ChildTable TSR1 
JOIN MasterTable SR ON TSR1.MasterTableId = SR.Id
JOIN ChildTable TSR2 ON TSR2.MasterTableId = SR.ParentId
WHERE SR.ParentId IS NOT NULL
```

Can anyone suggest an efficient query for above copying of data?

Comment: `what I have tried is first inserted...` <= please [edit] your question and add this query along with the update statement you run after.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? By looking at the sample data, it looks like both tables are the same with `+100` on fields `Id` and `ParentId` (apart from the `Id` of the 3rd row, that translates from `2` to `103` - but might also be a typo)

Comment: Edited the question hope will make more sense.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I updated the tag